# Java reading and writing High Scores

Tags: java

I am currently writing a program to play a game of pig for my Java class and cannot figure out how to read and write the high scores to and from a file.  I would like any possible assistance with this program. Thank YOU! The code compiles just fine right now and runs properly, This is the user v.s computer code for the game. This is my code so far:

````
public class ComputerPig
{
    //Scanner usersName;
    String usersName="";
    Boolean humanTurn = true;
    Boolean computerTurn = true;
    int dice;
    int humanTurnPoints, computerTurnPoints;
    int humanTotalPoints = 0;
    int computerTotalPoints = 0;
    private Scanner keyboard;
    private Scanner key;
    // System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
    // usersName = new Scanner(System.in);
    // setStart(usersName.nextLine());
    public void roll()
    {
        dice = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    }
    public int humanTurnScore()
    {
        {
            humanTurnPoints = dice + humanTurnPoints;
            System.out.println(usersName + "threw: " + dice);
            System.out.println(usersName + "have scored: " + humanTurnPoints + " in your turn.");
        }
        return humanTurnPoints;
    }
    public void humanTurnZero()
    {
        humanTurnPoints = 0;
    }
    public int computerTurnScore()
    {
        {
            computerTurnPoints = dice + computerTurnPoints;
            System.out.println("Computer has scored: " + computerTurnPoints + " in its turn.");
        }
        return computerTurnPoints;
    }
    public void computerTurnZero()
    {
        computerTurnPoints = 0;
    }
    public ComputerPig(String xUsersName)
    {
        usersName=xUsersName;
        humanGame();
        if (!humanTurn)
        {
            computerTurn();
        }
    }
    public int humanGame()
    {
        System.out.println("To start the game please press 'r'.");
        key = new Scanner(System.in);
        String start = key.nextLine();
        if (!start.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
        {
            System.out.println("Make sure you are pressing 'r'.");
            humanGame();
        }
        if (start.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
        {
            System.out.println(usersName + "pressed +  'r'.");
            System.out.println("Lets start.");
            do
            {
                roll();
                if (dice == 1)
                {
                    System.out.println(usersName + " got 1 and you lost your turn.");
                    System.out.println("Computer's GRAND TOTAL score is: " + computerTotalPoints);
                    humanTurnZero();
                    computerTurn();
                }
                else if (dice != 1)
                {
                    humanTotalPoints += dice;
                    if (humanTotalPoints >= 100)
                    {
                        System.out.println(usersName + " threw: " + dice);
                        System.out.println(usersName +" r GRAND TOTAL score is: " + humanTotalPoints);
                        System.out.println("Congratulations, you win!");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    humanTurnScore();
                    System.out.println(usersName +" r GRAND TOTAL score is: " + humanTotalPoints);
                    System.out.println("Computer's GRAND TOTAL score is: " + computerTotalPoints);
                    System.out.println(usersName + " can hold or roll again.");
                    System.out.println("To roll again press 'r' or 'h' to hold.");
                    keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String choice = keyboard.nextLine();
                    if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
                    {
                        System.out.println(usersName + " pressed 'r'.");
                        System.out.println("Lets roll again.");
                        roll();
                        if (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
                        {
                            System.out.println(usersName + " didn't press 'r'. To make sure the program is running correctly please press 'r' to roll or 'h' to hold.");
                            humanGame();
                        }
                    }
                    if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("h"))
                    {
                        System.out.println(usersName + " pressed 'h' and loose your turn.");
                        System.out.println(usersName +" r Grand total is: " + humanTotalPoints);
                        humanTurnZero();
                        computerTurn();
                    }
                }
            } while (humanTurn);
        }
        return dice;
    }
    public int computerTurn()
    {
        System.out.println("Now it's computer turn.");
        do
        {
            roll();
            if (dice != 1)
            {
                computerTotalPoints += dice;
                if (computerTotalPoints >= 100)
                {
                    System.out.println("Computer threw: " + dice);
                    System.out.println("Computer's GRAND TOTAL score is: " + computerTotalPoints);
                    System.out.println("Game Over! the computer wins");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                System.out.println("Computer threw: " + dice);
                System.out.println("Computer's GRAND TOTAL score is: " + computerTotalPoints);
                System.out.println(usersName + "r Grand total is: " + humanTotalPoints);
                computerTurnScore();
                roll();
            }
            if (dice == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("Computer thrown 1 therefore it's your turn now.");
                computerTurnZero();
                humanGame();
            }
            if (computerTurnPoints >= 20)
            {
                System.out.println("Computer scored already " + computerTurnPoints + " you'd better start to focus.");
                System.out.println("Please play again");
                humanGame();
            }
        } while (computerTurn);
        return dice;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter your name:");
        Scanner vScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String vUserName=vScanner.nextLine();
        new ComputerPig(vUserName);
        vScanner.close(); 
        HighScore.main(null);

    }
}```
````

Comment: Why do you open three Scanners to System.in - one is enough

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plain text file, or you could learn about JSON, and even more specifically, GSON.

What information specifically do you want stored in the file? Have you even tried to accomplish this? Paste your Highscore code.